# Putting a little space between column headers

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, controltemplate

In WPF I'm using custom ColumnHeaderStyle ...

```
             <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Border Background="#3ec9ed"
                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Padding="10"
                                        CornerRadius="25">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding"
                            Value="15" />
                    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush"
                            Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Now it looks like this.

[image]

I want to add a little space between every column header. Like this

[image]

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid`wraps all column headers into a common top level `DataGridColumnHeader` container (it's basically a big single column that contains the individual column headers).
When you set the `DataGridColumnHeader.Background` via the global `Style` the value also applies to this outer container which will in effect make the gap between the column headers disappear (because they share the same `Background`.

The solution is to set the `Background` for this top level column to e.g. `Brushes.Transparent`. The top level column usually has a `DataGridColumnHeader.DisplayIndex` of `-1`.
This allows us to address this special column using a template `Trigger`.

You must also wire your template elements to the templated parent properly in order to allow the `DataGridColumnHeader` properties like `Background` or `Margin` to behave as expected (i.e. to have any effect on the layout). You usually use the `TemplateBinding` markup extension for this.

To enable styling of the first and last item/column border  individually (to apply the round corners), you need a `MultiBinding` with a custom `IMultiValueConverter`. The purpose of this converter is to detect the last item/column.
The `ItemIndexComparerConverter` from the below example allows to specify the index of the item of interest using the [Index notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator-) (for example `^1` to reference the last item or `1` to reference the second item). Simply pass the index value of the desired column to the `MultiBinding.ConverterParameter` property.

The fixed and improved `Style` that applies a gap between the columns of 10 DIP (`Margin` left and right of 5 DIP) could look as follows:

```xml
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="5,0" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="#3ec9ed" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
          <Border>
            <Border x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    CornerRadius="0">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
          </Border>

          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            <!-- Set the top level column header that contains the individual table column headers 
                 to have a Transparent background in order to make the gaps visible -->
            <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex"
                     Value="-1">
              <Setter Property="Background"
                      Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>

            <!-- Round corners on the left for first column's border -->
            <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex"
                     Value="0">
              <Setter TargetName="Border"
                      Property="CornerRadius"
                      Value="25,0,0,25" />
            </Trigger>

            <!-- Round corners on the right for last column's border -->
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
              <DataTrigger.Binding>

                <!-- Pass '^1' as  ConverterParameter to indicate that the Converter has to find the last column -->
                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="^1">
                  <MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <local:ItemIndexComparerConverter />
                  </MultiBinding.Converter>
                  <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                           Path="DisplayIndex" />
                  <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" />
                </MultiBinding>
              </DataTrigger.Binding>

              <Setter TargetName="Border"
                      Property="CornerRadius"
                      Value="0,25,25,0" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

**ItemIndexComparerConverter.cs**
Converter that returns `true` when the `Index` reference value of the `MultiBinding.ConverterParameter` equals the item's index, otherwise `false`.
Required input (via `MultiBinding`) is the current item's index and the `ItemsControl` of the related items source collection.

```cs
public class ItemIndexComparerConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (parameter is not string referenceIndexText
      || values.FirstOrDefault(item => item is int) is not int indexOfCurrentItem
      || values.FirstOrDefault(item => item is ItemsControl) is not ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
      return false;
    }

    Index referenceIndex = referenceIndexText.StartsWith('^')
      ? Index.FromEnd(int.Parse(referenceIndexText[1..]))
      : Index.FromStart(int.Parse(referenceIndexText));
    int trueReferenceIndex = referenceIndex.GetOffset(itemsControl.Items.Count);

    return indexOfCurrentItem == trueReferenceIndex;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```